# Problem with Profiles in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I made an ASP .net application which use the asp .net login system. I use the a class which gets some details of the logged in user such as Name, address etc. In the page that the user can change his details i have those commands. If i don't use the commands in the page_load the address changes in the database successfully, but if i use them the database doesnt make the changes in the address. How is it possible? The profileC class uses the Inherits from ProfileBase class

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            classes.ProfileC pr = classes.ProfileC.GetProfileC(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

            TxtAddress.Text = pr.UserAddress;

        }

    }

    protected void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        classes.ProfileC pr = classes.ProfileC.GetProfileC(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        pr.UserAddress = TxtAddress.Text;

        pr.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that just by accessing pr.UserAddress that prevents the save in BtnAdd_Click or are you saying if you try to change the address in page load then call pr.Save, it doesn't save?

Comment: I think he's saying that if he takes the code out of `Page_Load` he can set it. With the code in `Page_Load` he cannot - Hence my answer - Needs the `if !IsPostBack` test in `Page_Load` as it's resetting the textbox text before the save operation happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `If !IsPostback` in your `Page_Load` with your current logic inside the `if`.

Don't forget when you press a button `Page_Load` will fire before the `BtnAdd_Click`